# How to create JavaScript object fields with the default values? (AngularJS model related)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller, mvvm, breeze

I am trying to create model layer for AngularJS application. There is good advice https://medium.com/opinionated-angularjs/angular-model-objects-with-javascript-classes-2e6a067c73bc#.3bjnrxun1 to use function for creating object:

```
function User(firstName, lastName, role, organisation) {
  // Public properties, assigned to the instance ('this')
  this.firstName = firstName;
  this.lastName = lastName;
  this.role = role;
  this.organisation = organisation;
}
```

What I am trying to do is to create default constructor with no arguments, e.g.

```
 function User() {
  // Public properties, assigned to the instance ('this')
  this.id = getNewId(); //special function that retrieves sequence from database 
  this.firstName = '';
  this.lastName = '';
  this.role = '';
  this.organisation = getDefaultOrganization();
}
```

I guess that is fine and it should work. But I am uneasy about code this.firstName = ''; I would be happy just declare fields and let JavaScript runtime assign any default value that is provided by JavaScript types.

I would be more happer to have and use AngularJS model framework if such exist instead of creating on for myself. I have taken look on BreezeJS but I am suspicous because of two aspects. First - their web page is somehow strange (although it contains lot of good documentation) and it doesn't provide impression about strong community and thriving projcet. Second - I use Laravel as backend and there seems to be no support for Laravel at present.

Answer (score 1):

you can use ecma script  future
https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters
without the socond function or

```
 function User(firstName, lastName, role, organisation) {
 // Public properties, assigned to the instance ('this')
 this.firstName = firstName||"Lorem";
 this.lastName = lastName||"ipsum";
 ...
```

}